# Don't check out document when workflow update it?

Tags: workflow, document-library

I have a document library with a simple workflow that when an item gets approved it gets copied over to another document library, I want to keep track of when this happened so I save the current date on the first library, the issue is that when I set this date the document gets updated and goes from draft -> approved -> draft in a minute. Is there a way I can keep the document in approved state if it was a workflow (sharepoint designer) who updated it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SharePoint 2010, you should be able to edit the approval task process and locate an activity that actually approves a major version of document. you can set the date right before that activity.